# How to disable snapshot in Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Snapshots cause a lot of cost. In some of my storage accounts I don't need them.

But I can't find a place where I can turn it off.

How can I disable snapshots completely from a storage account in Azure?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a feature that can be turned off completely; Although to make snapshots you would have to explicitly write code to create them, unless you have soft delete enabled. In that case an overwrite will create a snapshot in deleted state but it'll be automatically removed once the soft delete time expires.

Another option would be the lifecycle management. There you can make a rule to automatically delete snapshots once they are more than X days old. That check runs daily so the storage costs are only extended by a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your storage account's blob and look for your snapshots under Snapshots. From there, you may manage them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw0Zt.png

If you've already established a resource for it, go to that resource's page and delete it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76yHT.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. Your answer is essentially about how to delete a snapshot whereas OP is looking for a mechanism to disable snapshots functionality so that no snapshots can be taken.